# KeyError when trying to select subset of DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting a KeyError on my 'Ticker' column when trying to select only AAPL stock and I'm not sure why... I've also tried using `aapl = all_data.loc[all_data['Ticker'] == 'AAPL']`

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get(tickers, startdate, enddate):
    def data(ticker):
        return (pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=startdate, end=enddate))
    datas = map (data, tickers)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'GOOG']
all_data = get(tickers, datetime.datetime(2006, 10, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
print(all_data.head())

aapl = all_data[all_data['Ticker'] == 'AAPL']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you you are looking for

```py
all_data[all_data.index.get_loc("AAPL")]
```

outputs

```
                        High        Low       Open      Close       Volume  \
Ticker Date                                                                  
AAPL   2006-10-02   2.709643   2.653571   2.682143   2.673571  712639200.0   
       2006-10-03   2.676786   2.613929   2.658929   2.645714  790708800.0   
       2006-10-04   2.695000   2.612857   2.646429   2.692143  829082800.0   
       2006-10-05   2.720000   2.647500   2.661786   2.672500  683883200.0   
       2006-10-06   2.680000   2.636071   2.657857   2.650714  466958800.0   
...                      ...        ...        ...        ...          ...   
       2011-12-23  14.413929  14.267500  14.274643  14.404643  269399200.0   
       2011-12-27  14.610357  14.393572  14.396428  14.518929  265076000.0   
       2011-12-28  14.580358  14.333571  14.531786  14.380000  228662000.0   
       2011-12-29  14.487500  14.303928  14.407143  14.468572  215978000.0   
       2011-12-30  14.510000  14.410357  14.411072  14.464286  179662000.0
```